Describing polygons from enterprise geodatabase
My ArcGIS Pro 3.0.2 script accepts a list of multiple polygon feature layers in the ToC. I can iterate and name the polygons but when I try to Describe those layers it thinks they do not exist.
We access the polygon layers through an enterprise geodatabase. We connect to a folder that contains layer files pointing to the geodatabsae. The layer source is

I intend to read columns, use intersection commands to extract column values from the polygons and with a multi point file.

Can I get a read only hold of an EGDB layer to do some work with it? I am not editing.
Do I need a different connection to the EGDB?

param0 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
polygons = param0.split(';')

arcpy.AddMessage(polygons)
    
for poly in polygons:
    arcpy.AddMessage(poly) <- WORKS
    desc = arcpy.Describe(poly) <-FAILS
        

Output:
["'SDE POLYGON'"]
'SDE POLYGON'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\References\ARC\ArcScripts\ArcPro\NameToAttribute.py", line 44, in <module>
    # Tool parameter accessed with GetParameter or GetParameterAsText
  File "D:\References\ARC\ArcScripts\ArcPro\NameToAttribute.py", line 18, in ScriptTool
    arcpy.AddMessage(polygons)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 1275, in Describe
    return gp.describe(value, data_type)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 384, in describe
    self._gp.Describe(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))
OSError: "'SDE POLYGON'" does not exist


Using GetParameter instead of GetParameterAsText returns the list of layer names as a list of layers instead, that can be accessed as layer objects.
https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/how-to-get-a-layer-object-from-input-parameter-by/td-p/80592
Answer from link:

Why not use GetParameter instead of GetParameterAsText, using the
former passes you a reference to the layer object so you don't have to
create another reference.

